# Get near by friends using facebook in android programatically

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get near by friends using Facebook android, if it is possible, how can i get nearby by friends.Can any one help me..

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried ?

Comment: I searched about it but i didn't found any information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is not exposes in the Graph API, so no, it's not possible (and there's no workaraound).